# How to throw an exception from a server API code in Dart?

Tags: dart, rpc

I'm developing a client-server application in Dart and have been following the [tutorial](https://dart-lang.github.io/server/codelab/). My server code is roughly based on it.

In my server API code, when something goes wrong, I want to throw an exception, for example:

```dart
void checkEverything() {
  if(somethingWrong)
    throw new RpcError(400, "Something Wrong", "Something went wrong!");
}

@ApiMethod(path: 'myservice/{arg}')
Future<String> myservice(String arg) async {
  checkEverything();
  // ...
  return myServiceResponse;
}
```

and that exception should be processed in the main server, e.g.

```dart
// ...
var apiResponse;
try {
  var apiRequest = new HttpApiRequest.fromHttpRequest(request);
  apiResponse = await _apiServer.handleHttpApiRequest(apiRequest);
} catch (error, stack) {
  var exception = error is Error ? new Exception(error.toString()) : error;
  if((error is RpcError && error.statusCode==400) {
    // My code for creating the HTTP response
    apiResponse = new HttpApiResponse.error(
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Something went wrong", exception, stack);
  }
  else {
    // standard error processing from the Dart tutorial
    apiResponse = new HttpApiResponse.error(
        HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, exception.toString(),
        exception, stack);
  }
}
```

(snippet, see the [tutorial](https://dart-lang.github.io/server/codelab/) for the complete code sans my error handling).

However, my exception never reaches the above `catch` clause. Instead, it seems to get caught in `_apiServer.handleHttpApiRequest(apiRequest);`, which, in turns, throws INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR (500):

```
[WARNING] rpc: Method myservice returned null instead of valid return value
[WARNING] rpc:
Response
  Status Code: 500
  Headers:
    access-control-allow-credentials: true
    access-control-allow-origin: *
    cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
    content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    expires: 0
    pragma: no-cache
  Exception:
    RPC Error with status: 500 and message: Method with non-void return type returned 'null'

Unhandled exception:
RPC Error with status: 400 and message: Something went wrong!
#0      MyApi.myservice (package:mypackage/server/myapi.dart:204:24)
[...]
```

This is not very specific for the client. I'd like to communicate that an error has happened, not to return a good-looking response. So what is the proper way of handling server-side exceptions in Dart and passing that information to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I solved the problem. The `throw` clause apparently has to be in the API method itself, and not in a subordinate method. I.e.:

```dart
@ApiMethod(path: 'myservice/{arg}')
Future<String> myservice(String arg) async {
  if(somethingWrong)
    throw new RpcError(400, "Something Wrong", "Something went wrong!");
  // ...
  return myServiceResponse;
}
```

and not:

```dart
void checkEverything() {
  if(somethingWrong)
    throw new RpcError(400, "Something Wrong", "Something went wrong!");
}

@ApiMethod(path: 'myservice/{arg}')
Future<String> myservice(String arg) async {
  checkEverything();
  // ...
  return myServiceResponse;
}
```